# Find two different pairs of integers $a,b$ satisfying $(a,b)=10$ and $[a,b]=100$

Tags: number-theory

Since $(a,b)=10$, we can assume $a=10m$, $b=10n$ and $(m,n)=1$.

Want $[a,b]=100$. But $a$ and $b$ have gcd, which is $10$. So $[a,b]=100$ is amount to $[m,n]=10$. Hence the two paris are $(1,10)$ and $(2,5)$.

Actually, I came up with this solution when I tried to ask. I'm not sure whether it is fully correct. If I'm correct, how can I organise the language? Like the pairs $(1,10)$, $(2,5)$ may be ambiguous with gcd. Is there any other way to solve this question?

Comment: We also have $[a,b] =\frac{ab}{(a,b)}$.

Comment: $(1,10)$ and $(2,5)$ are values of $(m,n)$.

Comment: Don't quite understand. If we move $(a,b)$ to the right, what does it mean $[a,b](a,b)=AB$?

Comment: @Abstraction Wow, I forgot to multiply the gcd back-,-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two positive integers is the product of their gcd and lcm, that is
$$ab=(a,b)[a,b]$$

The proof is easy. Think on what exponent has in each side every prime that divides $a$ or $b$ (or both).

So we have $ab=1000$.

Also,
$$\frac{a}{(a,b)}\frac{b}{(a,b)}=\frac{1000}{100}=10$$
Since $a/(a,b)$ and $b/(a,b)$ are coprime, then $a/(a,b)$ is $1,2,5$ or $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. It is a special case of a general technique of reduccing to the coprime case when we have *distributive* operations such as gcd and lcm. Let's do it that way.

Cancel $\ (a,b)=10\,$ from both reduces them to $\ (\bar a,\bar b)=1,\  \overbrace{[\bar a,\bar b]}^{\large  \bar a\,\bar b}= 10,\  $ for $\ \smash[b]{\begin{align} \bar a=a/10\\ \bar b = b/10\end{align}}$

Thus the problem reduces to splitting $10=\bar a \bar b\,$ into coprime factors two ways, which is easy, namely $\ 1\cdot 10 = 10 = 2\cdot 5.$

---

Note that said *cancellation* implicitly uses the *distributive law* for gcd and lcm to distribute out the common factor $\, c= 10\,$ that we seek to cancel, i.e. it uses the properties.

$$\begin{align} (ac,bc) &= (a,b)c\\ [ac,bc] &= [a,b]\,c\end{align} $$

So these distributive laws are one way to make *rigorous* your "amounts to" claim. If you write out the details implicit in your proof you will see that it uses them (so some equivalent properties).

Answer (score 0):

Every one of $a,b$ is a multiple of $10$ and divides into $100$, so they can each only be $10,20,50,100$  To have the GCD be exactly $10$, we either need one to be $10$ or to have one be $20$ and another be $50$.  To have the LCM be exactly $100$ we either need one to be $100$ or one be $20$ and another $50$.  We might as well assume $a \le b $ and permute.  This means we can have $(10,10),(10,20),(10,50),(10,100),(20,50)$. Out of these, all are accepted except $(10,10)$ due to the condition of the numbers being *distinct*.

Comment: $[10,10] = 10$.